# Beaming to rests in the staff in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

How do I beam from a series of notes to a rest at the same vertical position as a rest in a way that looks appealing? Relevent snippet:

```
\version "2.20.0"

\new Staff {
        c'16[ c' \override Rest.staff-position = #1 r ]
}
```

[What it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSsy8.png)

Answer (score 3):

I think the property you are looking for is `Staff.Beam.positions`, which takes a pair of numbers and sets the beam anchor points, left and right, respectively. The property `Stem.length` only works for non-beamed stems. I personally like to change `Stem.stemlet-length` to a value larger than zero when beaming from/over/to a rest, as shown in my example below. Just delete that line if that's not to your liking and lower the `Beam.positions` to taste.

```
\version "2.20.0"

\new Staff {
    \override Staff.Beam.positions = #'(3.5 . 3.5)
    \override Staff.Stem.stemlet-length = #0.75
    c'16[ 
    c' 
    \override Rest.staff-position = #1 
    r ]
}
```

Result:

[image]